# Thymeleaf sec:authorize is not working on spring application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I making the header of my website for an assignment and I wanted to be able to disply different things depending if they are logged in or not. Problem is sec:authorize is not working with no errors or warnings to indicate why.

Here is my header file where I am trying to dispaly login & register if they are not logged in and logout if they are. But all of them appear no matter what.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<header class="masthead mb-auto" th:fragment="header">
    <div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
            <div class="inner">
                <div  class="Lucida_Handwriting">
                    <a class="Lg" href=".." >
                        <h3 class="logo-brand" id="Logo">Divorce app</h3>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="/" th:href="@{/}">Home</a>
                    <a sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()" class="nav-link" href="/login" th:href="@{/login}">Login</a>
                    <a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="/logout" th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a>
                    <a sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()" class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="/register" th:href="@{/register}">Register</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are my dependecies among others. Version of `spring-boot-starter-security` & `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` is 3.0.1

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also noticed that it gets passed in the html altho I think it should not do that

```
<a sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()" class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
<a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="/logout">Logout</a>
<a sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()" class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="/register">Register</a>
```

Tried using `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` but it didnt work.
Tried using older versions of `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5` but that didnt work either.
Tried replacing `xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5"` with  `xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"` but it didnt work.

EDIT: Added the html code instead of an image

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Instead add the text to the question, formatted appropriately. [Reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365).

Comment: @EliteOneTube, if you see sec:authorize in the generated html, then Thymleaf, for some reason, failed to process the file. Remove the version (3.1.1) from the pom and rebuild the project.

Comment: if you use `spring-boot-3` then you need `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6`

Comment: @dsp_user Removed the version, rebuilt it but same outcome. Stills appears in the generated html

Comment: @DirkDeyne switching to 6 worked, thank you!